# SQL : Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a code :

```
$id=implode(",",$selected);

$query = "SELECT u.id, p.brand, n.number FROM `user` u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `phone` p ON u.id = p.id LEFT OUTER JOIN `number` n 
ON p.id = n.id WHERE u.id in ($id)";
```

Where $selected is an array `array(1,2,3)`. But when i run it, it appears this notice :

> Unknown column '1' in 'where clause'

How to handle this problem? Thank you

Comment: `echo $query;` What is it?

Comment: It's giving you `u.id in (1,2,3)`. In SQL usually numbers are understood as column numbers, for values you need `'1','2','3'` and then Hemant's answer makes sense there. And then there's the security flaw McAdam commented about: you are not using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can do it like :

```
$id = implode("','",$selected);
```

This query will run :

```
$query = "SELECT u.id, p.brand, n.number FROM `user` u LEFT OUTER JOIN `phone` p ON u.id = p.id LEFT OUTER JOIN `number` n 
ON p.id = n.id WHERE u.id in ('$id')";
```

Comment: I understand that you're trying to demonstrate how the `IN` clause should be used, but this doesn't help the OP who is trying to do it using a parameterized query.

Comment: @McAdam331 It actually does help him, his problem is not using quotes around the values, so `1` (the first array value) is interpreted as a column name and not a value. With that said, he should probably consider using prepared statements or at a minimum sanitizing the input values.

Comment: @Juan That makes sense now that you've explained it to me, but the answer may not have been intuitive to a newbie (since it wasn't intuitive to me), so it could be edited to explain that.

Comment: I have fixed the query for the question.

Comment: Hello, i tried your suggestion but it still give an error, so i add '' in `('$selected')` part, thank you ;)